# How to fix No I2c device exists for bus ID1 (GrovePi .net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm making a .net core API to control the led lights from my pi, but I'm facing the following error: System.ArgumentException: 
No I2C device exists for bus ID 1.

I tried to find some info on how to find the busid of the grovepi but didn't came far. Tried also numbers 1 to 5 also didn't came far.

This is my code:
[1] https://gyazo.com/aa01ab3068201360c3ece14f125b1c45

My error: 
[2] https://gyazo.com/6bf3215e4466b02643b6a9eb92d12e52

I expected to turn the light on and get a page with some text but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue. I tracked the exception, it is thrown [here](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/9b56694a2ed14fd73ee19375ac442d85598462e7/src/System.Device.Gpio/System/Device/I2c/Devices/Windows10I2cDevice.Windows.cs). I posted an issue([#590](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/590)) in GitHub.

```
    public Windows10I2cDevice(I2cConnectionSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        var winSettings = new WinI2c.I2cConnectionSettings(settings.DeviceAddress);

        string busFriendlyName = $"I2C{settings.BusId}";
        string deviceSelector = WinI2c.I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector(busFriendlyName);

        DeviceInformationCollection deviceInformationCollection = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector).WaitForCompletion();
        if (deviceInformationCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"No I2C device exists for bus ID {settings.BusId}.", $"{nameof(settings)}.{nameof(settings.BusId)}");
        }

        _winI2cDevice = WinI2c.I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInformationCollection[0].Id, winSettings).WaitForCompletion();
        if (_winI2cDevice == null)
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException($"I2C devices are not supported.");
        }
    }
```

As we know, .net core 3.0 for IoT is preview. May i know why don't you consider to use traditional way to do that? A workaround is, you can host a web server in a UWP app, and you can add the LED control in the UWP app. Please refer to [IoTWeb](https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb).

Comment: Hi, Is the tradional way to use UWP ? If Yes I tried that but I want to turn the lights on and off from distance by just calling a api. I'm looking at the link you refered me right now.

Comment: Marking as answer since it's a bug, ty

Comment: @Ogie, yes, the IoTWeb actually is a traditional UWP, you can host web API in the app via socketstream.